# Why casting of primitive data types truncate floating-point values?

Tags: java, floating-point, logic, type-conversion

Casts of primitive types are most often used to convert floating-point values to integers. When we do this, the fractional part of the floating-point value is simply truncated.Why?

```
public class Chaz {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            double x = 1234.5678;
            long g = (long)x;
            System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: because long is integer it can't hold floating points

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? Are you asking why a long can't have a fractional part? Or are you asking why it is always truncating (=rounding down) rather than, say, rounding up, rounding .5 and higher up, or throwing an exception when it has to round?

Answer (score 2):

From docs,

> The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed
>   long has a minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of 2^63-1

It doesnot store decimal precision values. Please see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

`long` stands for long integer. I understand that the problem is data loss, but an integer can not store non-integers.

One can decide to store a multiplication of the number, like this:

```
public class Chaz {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            double x = 1234.5678;
            long g = (long)(x * 10000);
            System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

and then know that `g` is actually 10000x the real value. Or one can round it if the nearest integer is needed. We can't tell without additional information, but the thing we actually CAN tell, that this is a normal and expected behavior.